# SQL: group by from other table and invert result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have some problem with my SQL query
I have table `message` and table `recipient`

`message` is

```
ID    author    date
--------------------
0        1      2013-07-08 05:38:47
1        1      2013-07-13 05:38:47
2        1      2013-07-15 05:38:47
3        1      2013-07-15 05:38:47
4        2      2013-07-17 05:38:47
5        1      2013-07-28 05:38:47
```

`recipient` is

```
ID    m_id    recipient
--------------------
0        0      2
1        1      2
2        2      3
3        3      2
4        4      1
5        5      2
```

I need return *rows* from table `message` with group by **recipient column** from table `recipient` with last date in `message` table
I'll try this

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM message as m
INNER JOIN recipient as r ON (m.ID = r.m_id)
WHERE m.author = 1
GROUP BY r.recipient
ORDER BY m.ID DESC
```

return is

```
ID    author    date
--------------------
2        1      2013-07-15 05:38:47
0        1      2013-07-08 05:38:47
```

but i need

```
ID    author    date
--------------------
5        1      2013-07-28 05:38:47
2        1      2013-07-15 05:38:47
```

please help

I USE MySQL Server 5.1

---

I found a solution to my problem

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM recipient 
    WHERE 1=1
    ORDER BY recipient.ID DESC
) AS r
INNER JOIN message AS m ON (r.m_id = m.ID)
WHERE m.author = 1
GROUP BY r.recipient
```

just reverse table `recipient`

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Why are you returning two rows for one author?

Comment: What is the `GROUP BY` supposed to do?

Comment: **Missing**: Your RDBMS and version. Table definitions including NOT NULL, FK and PK constraints. How to break ties? What to do with missing recipients (if possible)?

Comment: Your test case is contradictory in multiple places. I assume this line in  message `2        2      3` should read `2        2      1` and the result should be `4        2      2013-07-17 05:38:47`, `5        1      2013-07-28 05:38:47` according to your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple and fast in **PostgreSQL** with `DISTINCT ON` - not standard SQL so not available in every RDBMS.

The question doesn't mention it, but deriving from the code examples it is actually looking for the row with the "last date" for each recipient ***for a given `author`***.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.recipient)  m.*
FROM   message   m
JOIN   recipient r ON r.m_id = m.id
WHERE  m.author = 1
ORDER  BY r.recipient, m.date DESC, r.m_id -- to break ties
```

Details as well as multiple SQL standard alternatives here:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Another solution with basic, standard SQL. Works with every major RDBMS, including **MySQL** (since that tag has been added):

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM   message   m
JOIN   recipient r ON r.m_id = m.id
WHERE  m.author = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   message   m1
   JOIN   recipient r1 ON r1.m_id = m1.id
   WHERE  r1.recipient = r.recipient 
   AND    m1.author = 1
   AND    m1.date > m.date
   )
```

Only the row with the latest date passes the `NOT EXISTS` anti-semi-join.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're using SQL-Server, you can use a [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT m.*,
      RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY r.recipient ORDER BY  m.date DESC)
    FROM message as m
    INNER JOIN recipient as r ON (m.ID = r.m_id)
    WHERE m.author = 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e1ca/2/0)